Detect verbosity level during ssh connection establishment
Is it possible to detect the verbosity level from a script during the ssh matching/connection process? (I'm using OpenSSH_8.9p1)
Sample:
~/.ssh/config
MATCH originalhost "somehost" exec "~/.ssh/some-script.sh '%h'"
  port 1234
  LocalCommand ~/.ssh/script2.sh
  ProxyCommand ssh reverse_server -W %h:$(~/.ssh/port-script.sh "%h")

The scripts should print some debugging information to stderr, but only if the verbosity is at least one.
ssh somehost -v

